# In the Netflix Umbrella Academy S2, why does "adult Five" know Luther's name?

Tags: tv, the-umbrella-academy

I have always assumed that Five doesn't have another name because he jumped into the apocalyptic future before robot mom gave the other kids names (One = Luther, Two = Diego, etc).

But in S2 of the Netflix show, when Luther and Five confront "adult Five" in the Irish pub, he knows Luther's name. The interaction goes, roughly:

> Luther: "It's me, Number One."

> Adult Five: "...Luther?"

This would imply that the kids got those names before Five jumped. Is there anything about this in the comics?

I can see why Five might not feel an attachment to his "mom-given" name if it was a fairly recent acquisition before jumping, but 1) wouldn't the others use it for him? and 2) wouldn't he be similarly un-attached to Luther's name and instead just call him "One"?

Comment: Just a hypothesis, maybe he learned their names during the time he was stuck in the future, or while he was a time-travelling assassin.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "Number Five had a name but it was unspoken for so long that all of his siblings, and Five himself, forgot what it was." There's no citation, that's why I just post it as a comment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Umbrella_Academy_characters#Number_Five_/_The_Boy_(Five_Hargreeves)

Comment: @tilley31 The Wikia for Umbrella Academy COMICS says "Number Five (no other birth name known or used)". You can check it out : https://umbrellaacademy.fandom.com/wiki/Number_Five

Comment: @Lime It seems like you should split this into 2 questions: 1) How come adult Five identified Luther by name? 2) When exactly were the Umbrella Academy members were given actual names?